# Unrelated downvotes because of criticism

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

So basically on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316844/find-the-median-of-the-sum-of-the-arrays) I attempted and failed to answer, I have been following it because I am interested in the solution. People have been posting answers to solve it (some similar or identical to mine). Since I've been looking at the problem the whole time I felt an obligation to tell some people they were incorrect (maybe a bit too insistently). However after one of my corrections, I noticed my reputation suddenly drop; when I looked at the cause I noticed that two of my questions (which is all of them btw) had been simultaneously downvoted. The chances of that are very slim (since the questions have no recent activity) so I assume someone got angry at me correcting them and decided to lower my rep.

My question is:  is there any recourse for this or any way to tell if I am just being a suspicious person?

Comment: aka ["serial](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) [downvoting"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) (or [Cereal downvotes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/cereal-downvotes))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two downvotes on your questions are too little for us to discern any kind of pattern (if that wasn't coincidental), even with the tools that moderators have available to us. If this continues, and you feel that there is a pattern to it, flag one of your answers and let us know.

The downvotes on your answers seem pretty well explained by the technical criticisms others brought up on those answers. I see no malice there.

Overall, I wouldn't worry about a couple of votes. Again, if this develops into a larger pattern, flag us and we'll take a look into it.

Comment: Thanks as I said I know my questions were bad (I can't delete them), I am glad to know that for more serious issues than mine there are tools to address the problem

Comment: @aaronman - I don't know, I don't think they're so bad. There are very good answers to them, too, so they're worth having around.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your questions actually show good quality, really.

[C++ garbage collected compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392128/c-garbage-collected-compiler) is a shopping question (recommendations). We are really not very fond of them here.

[Pointer vs. Reference in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785518/pointer-vs-reference-in-c) is closed as too localized.

You seem to be an avid answerer, but you should probably read the how-to-ask sections of the helpcenter a bit deeper, and focus on questions about actual problems you face.

Besides, it's only -4 (or is it -2?) rep.

Basically, the downvotes are probably warranted, and there's no issue here.
If the same user was to then systematically go through all of your answers and downvote, however, that would be automatically reversed.

Comment: Um I know the questions are crap, did you read this question, honestly it seems like you didn't read the question at all

Comment: Yes, I read it. I'm explaining that downvotes are used for lower quality posts. Only the stack exchange staff members can see who downvotes what, and users are free to downvote as they wish (however, malicious downvoting is automatically reversed by a script that runs daily)

Comment: how does the reversal system work, also I agree that the downvotes would be warranted except for the fact that they came at the same time over a month after I asked them, hence the posting of this question

Comment: Personally, I might see something someone's wrote, click their username, browse through their questions... and if they're crap, they get downvoted. This appears to be what you're describing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108538/shouldnt-anonymous-serial-downvoters-be-banned-from-so and see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

Comment: @DannyBeckett that is why I'm describing

Comment: @DannyBeckett be careful with that; it's autodetected and classed as vote fraud (due to not being "normal" use, even though it's warranted occasionally)

Comment: @Hiroto Usually I'll try to upvote something useful too, to counteract it, and encourage asking constructive questions.

Comment: @DannyBeckett honestly I'm more annoyed because in the link I posted for the question there are at least three incorrect answers posted and I really want someone to post the correct answer