# Is there a way to check to see why my question was downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [So annoyed with no-comment, vindictive downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting)

My question was recently downvoted and the person that did it never said why. Is there a way to see the reason why the person downvoted or perhaps who the person is so I may try and contact them?

To me, the downvote here is malicious. There is countless poor reasons to downvote what I believe to be a solid question. This is going to hurt my responses on this question, to which I may not find a satisfiable answer. At which point, I may be forced to ask again, therefore hurting the community with duplicate posts (this is due to the fact that downvoted questions get looked at less often then ones that are not).

Comment: Please post a link to your question

Comment: Presumably it's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639293/key-press-and-key-holding-for-win32).

Comment: It is ridiculous that even this post was closed, I would like to have a conversation about it and find out other reasons as to why this might happen. To me, "The Ghost of Christmas Past" is abusing the system and is just trying to get rep here.

Comment: @judeclarke: Closing questions does not award reputation... and seriously, a single downvote does not automatically take the question out of the front page. A question would need to have a net score of -3 (or even -5?) to disappear from the front page altogether. A single anonymous downvote doesn't mean anything. Also, you may want to provide evidence for this "fact" that downvoted questions get fewer views than others.

Comment: 1) No, there's no away to find out why it was downvoted 2) No, there is no way to find out who downvoted you or to contact them.  3) Reposting a question in order to erase a downvote is considered abuse.  4) Downvotes are not worth worrying over, especially when it's just one rare downvote occasionally.  If you don't understand the reason based on carefully re-reading your question, or based on comments others post, then it's usually best to move on without worrying about it further.

Comment: Also, you may find the answer to your question here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @judeclarke: Um, you might want to familiarize yourself with how the Stack Exchange sites work.  I don't gain any rep from closing your question, and as a [moderator for both Stack Overflow and for meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113294/november-2011-community-moderator-election-results) it's my *duty* to perform actions such as this.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn The number you're looking for is -4. :) (-8 if you're here on meta.)

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Users are not forced to comment/tell the reason to downvote. It's voluntary to post a comment.